# PHP array syntax/operator?

Tags: php, c, arrays, syntax, php-internals

When writing the syntax for an associative array in PHP we do the following

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

I am curious of the relationship of the `=>` syntax, or possibly operator. Does this relate to some kind of reference used in the hash table in ZE, or some kind of subsequent right shift or reference used in `C`? I guess I am just wondering the true underlying purpose of this syntax, how it relates to ZE and/or php extensions used to handle arrays, how it possibly relates to the written function in `C` before compiled, or If I just have no idea what I am talking about :)

Comment: It's just the `key => value` operator. It's used in foreach loops as well when you need the keys as well as the values of the array you're looping on.  In Javascript, the equivalent would be `var a = {foo: 'bar'}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=>` symbol a.k.a. `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` is just a parser token like `class`, `||` or `::`.

[`See: The list of php parser tokens`](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

It's nothing special apart from that fact that `"it looks like an arrow"` and it is used for `"array stuff"`.

Of course the exact usage is more complicated than that but [**`"array stuff"`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax) is the short inaccurate description that should do it.

It's used to represent `key` **=>** (**`points to`**) `value`

Comment: "The => symbol a.k.a. T_DOUBLE_ARROW is just a parser token like = or ||." This is more of what I was looking for. I guess now I just need to research how associative arrays are stored in hash tables.

Comment: @Headspin The word you are looking for when talking about php hash tables usually is `zval`. In php pretty much everything is a hash table but variables are stored in so called zvals.

Comment: thanks. I am actually looking into the daunting task of writing some PHP extensions which is what lead me to this question. While reading up on zvals specifically ha.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to that is no simpler than "It looks like an arrow".
It's not exactly the assignment operator per say because that would mean a variable-like assignment (like for the array itself). This is an array-internals specific assignment operator.

Webdevelopers are cool like that :P

Comment: Do you know the relationship to this within the hash table used to 'store' the array?

Comment: I don't see any relation, though that definitely doesn't mean there isn't one.

But trust me on this, don't use PHP like C. C is beautiful. PHP is hack-patchy-get-the-job-done.

What you asked is a classic example of how weird PHP can seem at times.

Comment: hehe, we both went with "it looks like an arrow" +1 ;)