# Is there any reason for using => instead of = in PHP when assign a value to array?

Tags: php

Please note that I have already read [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) and [What Does This Mean in PHP -> or =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037290/what-does-this-mean-in-php-or) and I know that what `=>` do in PHP.

My question is different.

Generally most programming languages use `=` to assign value to another.

**Example 01**

`$my_name = "I am the Most Stupid Person"; //Yes, that is my name in SO :-)`

**Example 02**

```
$cars = array();

$cars[0] = "Volvo";
$cars[1] = "BMW";
$cars[2] = "Toyota";
```

---

**Now let see following example.**

```
$myArray = array(
    0 => 'Big',
    1 => 'Small',
    2 => 'Up',
    3 => 'Down'
);
```

Here is also what happen is we have assigned 'Big' for `$myArray['0']`.

But here we used `=>` instead of `=`. Is there any special reason that **PHP was designed that way**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of => in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655336/use-of-in-php)

Comment: Perhaps because `=` is specifically assignment of value on the right to variable on the left, and array keys aren't variables (they're array keys), so something else is needed as a symbol to represent that

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510705/php-array-syntax-operator)/maybe dupe?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It is not a duplicate for this question because I am asking why => use instead of =. Please don't mark questions as duplicate questions without reading question carefully. Please...

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson if you know the use of it then you would know why is it used instead of the assignment operator

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile No I don't know and your linked question also NOT mentioned that why => used instead of =.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consistency of syntax is important, here I would say using `=>` in arrays is to ensure `=` still works. For example:

```
$a = 5;
```

Sets the variable `$a` to `5`.

```
$a = $b = 5;
```

Sets the variable `$a` and `$b` to `5`. That is `=` as an operator assigns the right hand side to the left hand side (if possible) and its result is also the right hand side. So now, in the context of an array:

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'foo'
  );
```

Now `$a[0]` is `'foo'`.

```
$a = array(
    0 => $b = 'foo'
  );
```

Now `$a[0]` and `$b` are both `'foo'`. Now think about this:

```
$b = 0;
$a = array(
    $b => 'foo'
  );
```

Simply means `$a[$b]`, that is, `$a[0]` is `'foo'`. If PHP used `=` for array keys:

```
$b = 1;
$a = array(
    $b = 'bar'
  );
```

What is the value of `$a`? Is it `[1 => 'bar']`? Or is it `[0 => 'bar']`? Did `$b` get the value `'bar'`? Or was it only used as a key?

As you can see, the parser would be very confusing this way, and there would be no way to allow keys defined by variables with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's because parser is written in that way.

Also it's more readable than `$variable = ""`, witch means `$variable now has value ""` instead of `'key' => ""` as `In array at position 'key' there is value ""`